# Mysql stored function giving different results than original query (some conditions are not working)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a weird problem in mysql stored function. The function is returning different result than if I run the query alone. Here is my function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` FUNCTION `getARetention`
(appID int(10), currentDate DATE) 
RETURNS int(11)
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

  RETURN 
(SELECT count(DISTINCT UserId)
           FROM
               Session 
       WHERE  (Date(Started) = currentDate  AND AppId=appID));
END
```

Here is how I call it:

```
SELECT getARetention(5,DATE('2013-04-03'));
```

Here is the alone query:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT UserId)
           FROM
               Session 
       WHERE  (Date(Started) = DATE('2013-04-03')  AND AppId=5)
```

The function is returning 2502 which is wrong. Alone query is returning 5, which is correct. Also, if I delete "AND AppId=5" from alone query then it return 2502, which means in the stored function that condition is not working.

Anyone have any idea why? I haven't used mysql for a while, so I am probably missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MySQL` cannot distinguish between the variable name and the column name here.

Name the variable otherwise:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` FUNCTION `getARetention`
        (
        _appID int(10),
        _currentDate DATE
        ) 
RETURNS int(11)
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
        RETURN  (
                SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserId)
                FROM   Session 
                WHERE  appId = _appId
                       AND started >= _currentDate
                       AND started < _currentDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
                );
END
$$
```